# Is there a way to change multiple items? [Hard to describe, example inside]

Tags: java

I'm struggling a bit in how to put this into words coherently, so I'll just use an example and hope it gets the message across.

Take the game Othello (Reversi) for example. I can program the logic behind the game, that is to say I can determine which pieces are to have their colors changed after each turn.

Let's say I've got 64 panels on a JFrame, each one representing a position on the Othello board. After a turn ends, I determine that panels 5 and 6 need to have their colors changed.

What I would like to be able to do is pass 5 and 6 via an array, let's say, and have a for-loop that runs through the array.

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
   change the image at array[i]
}
```

And, thus, only check for and make changes at the 2, in this example, places I need changed. Saving quite a bit of time writing code.

What I currently have to do is have a for-loop and inside the for-loop I have 64 if-else statements, saying

```
if(panel == 5){
    change the image at 5
}
etc.
```

I hope this successfully got across what I was trying to ask. If not, I'd be more than happy to clarify.

Comment: Are you using Swing components?

Comment: Yes I am. And I'm using the NetBeans GUI editor to design the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing the 64 sub-panels? If your existing code refers to panels as numbers from 0-63 (or 1 - 64) then you could store them in an single dimensional array and then your code yould be:

```
ImagePanel[] othelloPanels;

void changeImages(int[] indicies) {
    for (int i=0;i<indicies.length;i++) {
        othelloPanels[indicies[i]].change();
    }
}
```

I would have thought that storing them as two dimensonal (8 by 8) array makes more sense but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: Wow... I got so used to making arrays out of numbers and strings that I forgot you can make arrays out of pretty much anything. :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
void changeImages(Image[] images, Set<Integer> positionsToChange) {
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (positionsToChange.contains(i)) {
            // change the image at array[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the base of abhin4v's answer:

```
void changeImages(Image[] images, Set<Integer> positionsToChange) {
    for (Integer index : positionsToChange) {
        // change the image at images[index]
    }
}
```

you may put some additional checks in the `for` loop to be sure that your index is in bounds of your array, but it is not necessary, if you form Set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put your panels into map so that these panels could be easily addressed:

```
Map<Integer, PanelClass> panelsMap;
```

Where Integer key is an address of the panel in the map if you use one-dimensional addressing. When your method defines which panels to change it should return an array or Iterable of Integer, then do the following:

```
for(Integer coord : getPanelIdsToChange()) {
   panelsMap.get(coord).doWhatYouWant();
}
```